# Trouble with MYSQL Trigger Syntax in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, date, time, triggers, phpmyadmin

I need help with a trigger syntax in phpmyadmin. I have a table called `Log` with following columns:

```
ID, Client_Name, Employee_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Time.
```

First three columns are irrelevant to the trigger. `Start_Date` is a current timestamp, `End_Date` is a current timestamp on update.

The trigger is to be AFTER UPDATE Trigger. It should calculate the difference between Start_Date and End_Date in Hours in the `Time` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is explained in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). You can use `TIMEDIFF()` for calculating the elapsed time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE UPDATE ON Log FOR EACH ROW
 SET NEW.time=TIMEDIFF(NEW.End_Date,NEW.Start_Date);
```

**EDIT:** Above trigger needs to be *BEFORE* trigger to manipulate the data. Given the intended use mentioned in OP (update single column) in this should fine.

Comment: Okay, I rewrote it with BEFORE and now I get another error which I can't really figure out... "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4" 


`CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE UPDATE ON Log FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET
NEW.time=TIMEDIFF(NEW.End_Date,Start_Date)
END`

Comment: Sorry about the way I reply, not really used to having Enter as a send reply so I edit my comments often..

Comment: @DeanIvanov, I removed the `BEGIN` ... `END` so that you'll not run into problems with the delimiter. Give it a go now.

Comment: Thanks, now it works great :) If I want to later change it to display in minutes I should add 24*60 at the end, right?